# ISBN number writing into file

Tags: python

This is my code that takes an ISBN number that is in a file and then uses two partial sums and checks to see if it is divisible by 11 to make sure it is valid. My question is that I am supposed to write into a file the code I just tested followed by whether it is valid or invalid. I do not really understand files which is why I am asking for some help. The text written into the file is supposed to look like this:

0-1315-2447-X  valid
0-89237-010-9  invalid

#

```
def main():
    in_file = open('isbn.txt','r')
    for line in in_file:
        print(line)
        s1 = list(line)
    in_file.close()
    hyphen = '-'
    for i in s1:
        if i == hyphen:
            s1.remove (hyphen)
    print (s1)
    partial_sums(s1)

def partial_sums(s1):
    lst1 =[]
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if i == (len(s1) -1) and s1[i] == "X":
            sum = sum + 10
        else:
            sum = sum + int(s1[i])
        lst1.append(sum)
    print(lst1)
    sum_of_s1(lst1)

def sum_of_s1(s2):
    lst2 = []
    sum = 0
    for i in s2:
        sum += i
        lst2.append(sum)
    print(lst2)
    check(lst2[-1])
def check(value):
    if value % 11 ==0:
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("invalid")

main()
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name because Python has a built-in method [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logic of your code is correct, in order to write the output to a file, you need to have the line you read from the input file i.e., `s1` available in the `check` method. Since `check` method is where you decide if it is valid or invalid.

So in your `check` method do:

```
def check(value, s1):
    with open('output', 'a') as op_file:
    op_file.write(s1)
    op_file.write(' ')
    if value % 11 ==0:
        op_file.write('valid\n')
    else:
        op_file.write('invalid\n')
    op_file.close()
```

In order to have `check` method get access to `s1`, you have to pass `s1` as second parameter from function `partial_sums` to `sum_of_s1`. And from there to `check`.

Other things to note:

- It is advisable not to use `sum` as a variable name. `sum` is the name of a library function.
- In your `main` function, you can replace the code:

  ```
  hyphen = '-'
  for i in s1:
      if i == hyphen:
          s1.remove (hyphen)
  ```

  with:

  ```
  s1 = s1.replace('-', '')
  ```

Comment: You don't need to close the file if you are using a with statement, and your indentation is not correct for the with block.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = open('isbn.txt', 'r+').read().split()
num = []
for k in x:
    if k.isdigit() == True:
        num.append(k)

num = int(''.join(num))
if (num % 11 == 0):
    x.write('Valid\n')
else:
    x.write('Invalid\n')
```

Open the file, and append all the digits to a list. Then see if the integer value of these combined is divisible by 11. If it is, then print `'valid'`. Else, print `'invalid'`.

Comment: How does this answer the question, which is about writing to files?

Comment: Tried this and it said invalid interval for int()